# Dudas con String, buscar cuantas veces se repite una palabra en una oracion puesta por el usuario

Tags: java, array, string

Necesito algo de ayuda, ya que no se como realizar esto. Debo hacer que el programa analice un texto puesto por el usuario, luego le pida a este que introduzca una cantidad x de palabras a a buscar en el texto. Que diga cuantas veces se repitieron esas x cantidad de palabras en el texto.

Este es el intento que tuve, pero no hubo mucho exito y no se como avanzar, espero puedan ayudarme!

```
String texto = " ";
int contador = 0;

System.out.println("Ingrese el texto que desea crear: ");
texto = sc.nextLine();

System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de palabras que quiere buscar en el texto: ");
int palabras = sc.nextInt();

String [] palabra = new String[palabras];

for(int i = 0; i < palabras; i++) {
    
    System.out.print("Ingrese la palabra a buscar numero " + "[" + i + "]: ");
    palabra[i] = sc.next();
    
}

for(int k = 0; k < palabras; k++) {
    
    if  (texto.equals(palabra[k])) {
        contador++;
        
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < palabras; j++) {
        
        System.out.println(palabra[j] + ": " + contador);
        
    }
    
}
```

Disculpen lo feo del codigo, pero aun estoy aprendiendo, gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La mejor forma de afrontar el problema es usando un HashMap para guardar el número de veces que se repite cada palabra en el texto y luego consultar la frecuencia de las palabras que el usuario quiere conocer. Esta solución da una complejidad temporal lineal, ya que solo tienes que recorrer el texto una sola vez para obtener las frecuencias de todas las palabras.

Lo primero sería guardar en un `Map<String, Integer>` el número de veces que se repite cada palabra:

```java
Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
for (String word: texto.split("([,.\\s]+)")) {
    int oldCount = occurrences.getOrDefault(word, 0);
    occurrences.put(word, oldCount + 1);
}
```

Luego simplemente consultas la frecuencia de cada palabra que el usuario entró:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
    int repeticiones = occurrences.getOrDefault(palabra[i], 0);
    System.out.printf("La palabra %s se repitió %d veces. %n", palabra[i], repeticiones);
}
```

El código de manera íntegra quedaría:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String texto = " ";
int contador = 0;

System.out.println("Ingrese el texto que desea crear: ");
texto = sc.nextLine();

System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de palabras que quiere buscar en el texto: ");
int palabras = sc.nextInt();

String[] palabra = new String[palabras];

for (int i = 0; i < palabras; i++) {
    System.out.print("Ingrese la palabra a buscar numero " + "[" + i + "]: ");
    palabra[i] = sc.next();
}

Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : texto.split("([,.\\s]+)")) {
    int oldCount = occurrences.getOrDefault(word, 0);
    occurrences.put(word, oldCount + 1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
    int repeticiones = occurrences.getOrDefault(palabra[i], 0);
    System.out.printf("La palabra %s se repitió %d veces. %n", palabra[i], repeticiones);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, logre entender y funciono a la perfeccion, agradezco muchisimo la ayuda!